# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I am working on a practice project (TypeScript Project), and fetching a data from and endpoint. I am getting data correctly but when I try to assign it to my state `nft` using `setNft` useState hook, It throws me and error in `useEffect` at the end `setNft(data)`

**Interface**

```
interface Attributes {
  type: string
  value: string
}

interface Anu {
  name: string
  description: string
  file: string
  tokenstring: string
  contentType: string
  hathorLink: string
  attributes: Attributes[]
}
```

**Code**

```
  const [nft, setNft] = useState<Anu>()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://51.15.56.157:3000/anu/5000")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .then((data) => setNft(data))     <=== getting error here
  }, [])
```

[image: Error Image]

[image: Fetch data image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### The Problem

the problem is with the `then` chaining and `arrow function`.

> The then() method returns a Promise. It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

##### The solution

fix the errors by removing the second `then` or add the braces around the `console.log`

```
  const [nft, setNft] = useState<Anu>()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://51.15.56.157:3000/anu/5000")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setNft(data)) 
  }, [])
```

or,

```
  const [nft, setNft] = useState<Anu>()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://51.15.56.157:3000/anu/5000")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
          return result;      // ----> this return result will use as data in the next then !!
       })
      .then((data) => setNft(data)) 
  }, [])
```

**Note:** pay attention to my comment in the above snippet.

##### Explanation:

using arrow function in this way `(result) => console.log(result)` mean:

```
function sample (result) {
  return console.log(result)
}
```

in the `then` chaining, the callback function will **return** something that you may use in the **next** `then` but you **returned** a `console.log` instead of your **data**.

So your codes look like this which is clearly wrong and cause the error:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://51.15.56.157:3000/anu/5000")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((console.log(result)) => setNft(data))  
  }, [])
```